# How to use CUDA interop for rendering spheres?

Tags: opengl, cuda

I have a large number of spheres. I do a cudamemcpy and transfer mass positions , charge , initial velocity and radius to the device. I calculate the interactions between all the sphere and compute the final positions. My problem is I want to render these spheres

```
GLuint vbo[2];
glGenBuffers( 2, vbo);
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);

unsigned int size = numBodies * 4 * sizeof( float);
float4* initialpos = (float4*)malloc(numBodies*4*sizeof(float));
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numBodies; i++)
{
    // Initialize initialpos which are the centers of the spheres
}

glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, initialpos, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

free(initialpos);

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
// register vbo with CUDA
cudaGLRegisterBufferObject(vbo[0]);
cudaGLRegisterBufferObject(vbo[1]);

//inside the display function
float4* oldPos;
float4* newPos;
cudaGLMapBufferObject( (void**)&newPos, vbo[1-swap])
cudaGLMapBufferObject( (void**)&oldPos, vbo[swap]);
 //Call  a C function which calls LAUNCHES CUDA KERNEL with old and new Positions 
 // Unmap Buffer Objects
swap = 1 - swap;
```

I change newpos and oldPos in the kernel. Now to draw points  I would 
use a glDrawElements(GL_POINTS,.....);

My problem is how do I draw spheres with this data as each  of the 4 bytes of the  newpos    array has the centre of a sphere basically something like instead of GL_POINTS something like "GL_SPHERES".

Comment: Are You look at CUDA SDK example SimpleGL. It render in buffer with cuda and then draw result using opengl.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "GL_SPHERES" in OpenGL that simply lets you draw a sphere. You might want to raytrace a sphere using point sprites and GLSL shaders. The general idea is described in:

Stefan Gumhold: Splatting Illuminated Ellipsoids with Depth Correction. VMV 2003.

By the way: This is currently the fastest way to render a large number of spherical particles and it will give you perfect spheres. The "particles" demo in the Nvidia GPU Computing SDK does something similar to render the particle spheres. However, the spheres may not overlap in the Nvidia demo, since it doesn't handle sphere-sphere intersections due to the uniform depth values!